# How to make an inset border with padding

Tags: html, css, border, insets

I have this JsFiddle: [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/poldz123/dkqas4m5/)

```
       <div id='menu'>
            <ul>
                <li><a class='styleanchor' href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/mainpage/">
                    hone</a></li><!--  
                --><li><a class='styleanchor' href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/verification/user/">asdsad</a></li><!--  
                --><li><a class='styleanchor' href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/verification/user/">Replace this LOL</a></li><!--  
                --><li><a class='styleanchor' href=index.html>Replace this LOL</a></li><!--  
                --><li><a class='styleanchor' href=index.html>Replace this LOL</a></li><!--  
                --><li><a class='styleanchor' href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/verification/store/"></a></li> 
            </ul>   
        </div>
```

What I want to have my border more look like this the border in the image:

[image]

As you can see it has an inset border with padding on top and bottom i guess.

How can I achieve those using css? I tried adding padding to **li** but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question here is   [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dkqas4m5/12/)

```
a.styleanchor:hover:before
    {
        content: "";
       position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #ffffff;
    left: 43%;
    right:43%;
    bottom: 0;
    }
#menu {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        border-top: 1px solid gray;
        background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;

    }
```

Comment: hi yes you are almost right +1, By the way I want the border on the right side of genre,broadcast.community,etc as you can see in the image how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 3px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```